# Unable to open/copy files on an encrypted UNC share after reboot of file server

Tags: windows-server-2012, unc, encrypting-file-system

I have 2 Windows 2012 environments.  The first is a CMS that is accessing files on a the second server (file server).

One of the shares that I have on the file server is marked as encrypted.  When I set this up, everything works great, documents can be opened/modified/deleted from the CMS.  The user account on the CMS is the cert owner, and this exists in the keystore on both servers.

However, if the file server is rebooted *and no login takes place on the file server*, I can no longer open/modify documents on the encrypted share - even though I can actually traverse the share and see the files.

If I perform a login to the file server with the cert owner, then the share begins to work unexpectedly again.

I have been able to replicate this behavior in a couple environments, so I know this is a problem with default configurations (or something I am doing commonly wrong with the cert/share).

How can I get this to work consistently, without having to login to the file server following a reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working after enabled Delegation inside of AD for the file server COMPUTER, as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx